# Distributing Windows Store App Without Powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment, windows-store, ad-hoc-distribution

We have developed an app for Windows tablets. We have side loading key and certificates etc and can install the apps using the conventional methods.

We are looking, however, to be able to adhoc distribute these apps to our clients tablets without the client having to manually install the Side loading key and then running the Powershell script and not using Intune.

Ideally we would just be able to provide them a link that will trigger a download (like we can with iOS apps) or that will give them a file they can click to then trigger the install (like an exe or something).

Beta builder helps with this on iOS

Has anyone got any ideas how best to go about this or even better implemented it before?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft has chosen to restrict Windows 8 app sideloading to Windows 8 Enterprise Edition. Furthermore, Microsoft Active Directory Domain Services (ADDS) is required for this scenario.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx

**Note:** Of course, you can still apply for the developer sideloading key, but you already know about that.

Comment: Cheers Trev. We have side loading keys but want a 'one click' solution to be able to deploy them i.e. register them to the device and install the app at the same time. A bit like test flight does with iOS and android apps